# can't find symbol of super statement

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, symbols, super

This is a java code with inheritance and polymorphism methods.

Student Class

```
public abstract class Student
{
    protected long id;
    protected String name;
    protected String programCode;
    protected int part;

    public Student(){
        id=0;
        name=" ";
        programCode=" ";
        part=0;
    }

    public void setStudent(long i,String nm,String code,int pt){
        id=i;
        name=nm;
        programCode=code;
        part=pt;
    }

    public long getId()            {return id;}    
    public String getName()        {return name;}    
    public String getProgramCode() {return programCode;}    
    public int getPart()           {return part;}    
    public abstract double calculateFees();

    public String toString(){
       return ("ID: "+id+"\nName: "+name+"\nProgram Code: "+programCode+"\nPart: "+part);}
    }
```

FullTimeStudent Class

```
public class FullTimeStudent extends Student{
    protected String collegeName;
    protected String roomNumber;

public FullTimeStudent(){
    super();
    collegeName=" ";
    roomNumber=" ";
}    
public FullTimeStudent(long i,String nm,String code,int pt,
                              String collegeNm,String roomNum){
    super(i,nm,code,pt); //can't find symbol here
    collegeName=collegeNm;
    roomNumber=roomNum;
}    
public void setFullTimeStudent(String collegeNm,String roomNum){
    collegeName=collegeNm;
    roomNumber=roomNum;
}    
public String getCollegeName()   {return collegeName;}
public String getRoomNumber()    {return roomNumber;}

public double calculateFees(){
    double fee=0, collegefee=0, totalfee=0;

    if(programCode.equals("BIT")){
       fee=2000;
    }
    else if(programCode.equals("BCHE")){
       fee=2300;
    }
    else if(programCode.equals("BPHY")){
       fee=3200;
    } 
    else if(programCode.equals("BBIO"))
       fee=2700;
    } 

    if(collegeName.equals("Jati")){
       collegefee=200;
    }
    else if(collegeName.equals("Cengal")){
       collegefee=350;
    }
    else if(collegeName.equals("Dahlis")){
       collegefee=420;

       totalfee=fee+collegefee;
       return totalfee;
    }

public String toString(){
     return super.toString()+"\nCollege Name: "+collegeName+"\nRoom Number"+roomNumber;
}
```

}

It seems that it can't find the symbol of the super statement in the FullTimeStudent 
class.

```
super(i,nm,code,pt);
```

Comment: What do you expect that line to do?

Comment: Why do you have a `setStudent()` method instead of a constructor with the same parameters?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a public constructor for an abstract class - make it protected.

Answer (score 1):

As the error is trying to tell you, your superclass does not have any constructor that takes parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Change the method declaration of `Student#setStudent` to that of an overloaded constructor expected in the constructor of `FullTimeStudent`

```
protected Student(long i, String nm, String code, int pt) {
    id = i;
    name = nm;
    programCode = code;
    part = pt;
}
```

The no-args constructor can then be simplified to

```
protected Student() {
   this(0, " ", " ", 0);
}
```

(will leave the translation of literal values to predefined constants as an exercise)